# Weird type inference in Haskell

Tags: haskell

When asking GHCi the type of expression `2 . (+1)`, I am told of a type expression that doesn't make much sense to me:

```
Prelude λ : :type 2 . (+1) 
2 . (+1) :: (Num b, Num (b -> c)) => b -> c
```

How can a function `b->c` be of class `Num`?

Comment: The link from @amalloy explains something similar. Haskell number literals are overloaded, so they can have any type (as long as that type is an instance of `Num`).  You could (although it would be a terrible idea) define an instance of `Num` for functions, in which case the above would actually work.

Comment: *Any* type can be an instance of any given class - this is the open world assumption. `a -> b` can be an instance of `Num` if you write `instance (..) => Num (a -> b)` in a module and bring that module into scope. As an aside, there is a reasonable `Num a => Num (F a)` instance for any `Applicative F`, so the constraint `Num (a -> b)` is not even so crazy.